# Is there a way to display a line between labels and data columns in an Ext JS form?

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs

**How can I add a thin, gray line as shown here between the label and field columns of an Ext JS form?**

[image]

I drew the line above with a graphics program but the form itself is being created with this code:

```
var form_customer_contact = new Ext.FormPanel({
    frame:true,
    labelWidth: 140,
    labelAlign: 'left',
    bodyStyle:'padding:10px',
    width: 300,
    height: 600,
    autoScroll: true,
    itemCls: 'form_row',
    defaultType: 'displayfield',
    items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'Customer Contact',
            name: 'customerContact',
            allowBlank:false,
            value: 'Mr. Smith'
        },
        createCombo('Reason for Contact', 'reason', ['data correction', 'new contact', 'missing information']),
        createCombo('Result', 'result', ['new data', 'old data', 'other data']),
        createCombo('Communication', 'communication', ['telephone', 'fax', 'e-mail']),
        createCombo('Related Order', 'relatedOrder', ['345234534','3453453452', '2234234234'])
        , {
            fieldLabel: 'Date',
            xtype: 'datefield',
            name: 'theDate',
            format: 'd.m.Y',
            width: 150,
            id: 'theDate',
            vtype: 'daterange'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Time',
            xtype: 'timefield',
            name: 'theTime',
            format: 'h:i:s',
            width: 150,
            id: 'theTime'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Notes',
            name: 'relatedOrder',
            value: 'These are the notes and they are very long and these are more notes and they are very long and these are more notes and they are very long and these are more notes and they are very long and these are more.'
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could perhaps add a `border-right` to the `label.x-form-item-label` that's rendered by the ExtJS form elements. But that will end in a endless struggle with CSS because you have floated elements which don't have the same height.

The best way actually is to use a `background-image` either on the `div.x-form-label-left` that surrounds the `<form>` or on the `form.x-form` itself. Not nice but the only way we achieved what we wanted (and that's exactly what you've asked for).